# how to exactly match using :class selector in watir-webdriver

Tags: css-selectors, watir, watir-webdriver

Regarding the backwards-incompatible change of Watir 0.5.x
[Finding elements by :class now matches partial class attributes.](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/36)

How do I get the old behavior? I.e. to match exact class name.

It is breaking my code, in one case:

```rb
# expand all multiple records
 while  $browser.div(:class => "expander").exists?  
  $browser.div(:class => "expander").click
 end
```

because once `.click`ed, the `div`'s **class** becomes  **"expander hasChildren"** (and possibly other classes, depending on table row's color and content).   Is there a better way to write that code that expands all rows that are still collapsed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match the exact class name, you could use a regex with starting and ending anchors:

```
$browser.div(:class => /^expander$/).exists?
```

This would match exactly "expander" but not "expander hasChildren" or "something expander".

For your other question regarding if there is a better way to expand all rows, I think it really depends on what the HTML for the page looks like. Do you have an example? When I had a similar problem with a similar control, I was able to use the structure of the divs around the clickable ones to make the search more specific.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, only it's brittle.  Because every row's first expansion needs to make an AJAX call to fetch more records (I think that's what I noticed in the Firebug Console meanwhile), I'd get a `Element is no longer attached to the DOM` so I added `sleep 1` after the `.click` and it gets a lot farther down, but still errors like that and leaves the rest unexpanded.

Comment: Does the control support an expand-all option that perhaps your devs could enable, ore perhaps provide a method for that you could access via executing the js directly?

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden Unfortunately not, and I wish they were my devs; it is just another site I webdrive for customer accounts which I have no influence over.  But finding the right js to exec directly is an idea I could look into deeper (still would need some reliable indication that the DOM had finished updating, though, like `.wait_until_present` on something predicable)

Comment: Is the site using a 3rd party control?  (often findable via googling for stuff like classnames).  If so and you can find a demo site run by the vendor, it could provide a way for others here to look at both how the control works, and your logic for expanding. If you can find a demo site, start a new question about how to go about expanding all rows..   Speaking of which, for stuff like this where interacting with something changes it, one trick I've used is work from the bottom up, not the top down, when clicking on stuff that changes after you click it.

Comment: Two good ideas I hadn't considered. For the bottom-up approach I have to think about how to enumerate all `:class => /^expander$/` divs and how to write the for loop that clicks them in reverse.

Comment: UPDATE. I no longer consider this `/^classname$/` regex way a viable solution for my programs because compared to `"classname"` it is HORRIBLY SLOW in watir-webdriver.  Anybody know why?  I thought my software was locking up everywhere esp. around loops.  I began reverting back to the `"classname"` form in places hoping it's still unique enough to not grab the wrong element, or other workarounds. Sadly other locaters are not really available to me in most cases. Another painful lesson learned.