# Intermittant "Element is no longer attached to the DOM" errors using watir-webdriver

Tags: firefox, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I am using Watir-webdriver 0.5.3.  Before with versions circa 0.4.x this was never trouble:

```
 while  $browser.div(:class =>  /^expander$/).exists?   
  $browser.div(:class => /^expander$/).click; sleep 1.5
 end
```

The click causes some javascript to execute that changes the class for the div that was clicked, expanding a treeview control.  The objective of the script is to keep expanding nodes until there are none left unexpanded.

I am frequently getting  **"Element is no longer attached to the DOM"** on the *.exists?* line, which is esp. troubling, because the reason I began using `.exists?` extensively was to avoid such errors that immediately crash the script in the first place.

visually I do observe the expansion almost right away after the .click, and if I pause things right there, Firebug does confirm that the div with only class='expander' had been replaced with a div in its place with class='expander hasChildren expanded', and only that div.

The error seems to be coming up from webdriver.

Has anyone else had this problem or recommend workarounds?

In an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317245/how-to-exactly-match-using-class-selector-in-watir-webdriver) I needed to switch to the `/^expander$/` form to match exactly that class exclusively, after the new `watir-webdriver` behavior changed.

Comment: I'm beginning to think either `.exists?` doesn't see the new version of the DOM after it's been updated by some AJAX/Javascript, or it doesn't work at all with the element types and tag searches I often use.

Comment: it sounds a lot like some kind of race condition where the test is accessing the browser while the dom is still updating..  Is there some new object that is being 'created' that you could look for before you try to proceed..  could you perhaps keep a count of how many 'expander hasChildren' divs there should be and wait until the latest one shows up before moving on?

Comment: I tried things like `$browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicit_wait=10` or ridiculously long explicit sleep times but still same error, only longer waiting. This sort of problem has plagued me since I began using watir.  Is there some way to force a DOM re-read so my code can move on? (Or interrupt browser DOM updating then re-read, although I think I've tried `send_keys ESC` before)

Comment: More relevant answer to your question, visually I do observe the expansion almost right away after the .click, and if I pause things right there, Firebug does confirm that the div with only class=`expander` had been replaced with a div in its place with class=`expander hasChildren expanded`, and only that div. Even should it mistakenly get clicked again, it never goes back to `expander` but `expander hasChildren`

Comment: Yet that infernal error still happens sooner or later non-definitively, never on `.click` but oddly always on `.exists?` in this code sample.

Comment: I added the webdriver tag and edited the question a little to bring in some of the info from your comments, hoping maybe someone who knows webdriver better might be able to comment or propose a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
while  $browser.div(:class =>  /^expander$/).exists?
  count = $browser.divs(:class => 'expander hasChildren expanded').size   
  $browser.div(:class => /^expander$/).click
  $browser.wait_until{$browser.div(:class => 'expander hasChildren expanded', :index => count).exists?}
 end
```

The other approach I have used where actions are causing things to go away, is get a count, and then work by index, from the last item back towards the first, that way the 'next thing' you are addressing should still exist.  That can be more reliable than always addressing 'first one' where your prior action just removed 'first one'.   If expanding things opens up new 'expander' classes then you might have to do this in waves, where you end up expanding the first tier, then the second, etc till you see no more of them to expand.  it might mean making a method to expand all currently visible expanders, then checking when it is done to see if there are any visible expanders, and if so, call the method again.

Comment: Finally getting a chance to test this. It's giving me `can't convert FalseClass into an exact number` exception probably into `.wait_until()` Should those be `{}` instead? But I see what you're doing there. Studying http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/

Comment: Taking your comment's suggestion, what do you think about this: `hitlist = $browser.divs(:class =>  /^expander$/); hitlist.reverse.each {|r| r.click; sleep .1}; $browser.wait_until { $browser.divs(:class =>  /^expander$/).size < 1} `  Seems it will click all of them nearly simultaneously, but after the loop will wait till 0 of them are left

Comment: I think you'd have to try it and see, might depend a lot on the speed of the browser and it's ability to buffer actions while a js is running, or potentially some of the clicks could get missed.. but that's just a hunch, running it for real might be your best bet.    I'd try it with IRB myself, having watir open the browser, manually navigate to the page, then paste in the bit of code you want to test and see what happens.. some of this stuff, because of all the interaction between the browser, the JS modifying the dom, and the code driving the browser, you just don't know till you try it.

Comment: .wait_until wants an expression that will evaluate to true or false, not a code block, so the parenthesis should be correct.  if that is the line giving the error, I wonder if count is not an int for some reason?  I thought .size in the second line above would return an int, but maybe I'm confused about what method to use there, perhaps that should be `.length` (I tend to get confused between those two)

Comment: I have a hunch it's `.wait_until(seconds) { boolean test block }` but that watir link above appears outdated. 30sec default if () missing.  I think `.size` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```rb
Watir::Wait.until do
  $browser.div(:class => /^expander$/).click
  not $browser.div(:class => /^expander$/).exists?
end
```

Comment: Thanks but that also crashes, after expanding the first one on a page with only one expander record.  That first one does get clicked and expanded though, and gets a new `class="expander hasChildren expanded"`.

Comment: You just need to fix regex locator then. Try `$browser.div(:class => /expander/)` or, if you use latest Watir-WebDriver, it supports partial classes without regexp - `$browser.div(:class => 'expander')`

Comment: That takes me back to [square one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317245/how-to-exactly-match-using-class-selector-in-watir-webdriver) in which I had to retrofit all my old code with `/^...$/` regex instead of mere quotes, but thanks. I think [Chuck's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9436421/1069375) is generally what's affecting me; semantics deeper in the Selenium/DOM interaction than (I think) a Watir API user should have to worry about.

Comment: since both classnames start with expander, he needs to use a regex that matches that specifically hence the $/ anchor (due to the new partial classname match' capability added in recent versions).  if he just does a partial match, then it will be clicking the same one over and over and accomplish nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Chuck's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436421/1069375) this code also first enumerates all candidates that need clicking to get expanded or whatever, and then in a one-line foreach loop, clicks them from the bottom of the page going up:

```
hitlist = $browser.divs(:class => /^expander$/)  # put all candidates into an array

hitlist.to_a.reverse.each {|r| r.click; sleep 0.1}  # loop in reverse

$browser.wait_until { $browser.divs(:class => /^expander$/).size < 1}  # Wait until they're all AJAXed out of existence
```

Lines 1 & 2 could even be compacted to simply `$browser.divs(:class => /^expander$/).to_a.reverse.each {|r| r.click; sleep 0.1}` if you don't think the interim `hitlist` collection might be handy to have...but nevermind that.

Even though the code looks sound, my main concern here however is the very severe performance penalty using a regex locator like `/^expander$/` apparently has...not something they tell you in the docs!  Not something I faced pre 0.5.3 when standard, quoted class locators like `:class => "expander"` were exclusively matched.

Once or twice would be forgivable (in my case finding `div(:class => /^expander$/)` takes between 5-50 seconds in a <100kB html page *each time*) but I'm especially worried about line 3: who's to stay how many times the `{boolean test block}` gets executed to poll if the condition is finally met?

Comment: When I tried it, there is no `.reverse` but easy enough to fix using _Methods inherited from ElementCollection_ `#[], #each, #first, #initialize, #last, #length, #to_a` Just prepend a `.to_a`